# I want to export a jsp table of search results to an MS-Excel '.xlsx' format file

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, jquery

(Edited) Okay let me explain this a little better. I have search page which looks for employees based different search criterion. Now(Due to a scope creep that happened in the QA stage) I want to add an export button which will save the filtered list of employees in a MS-Excel form. I have been looking into Birt report design but I don think thats what I am looking for because its trying to build an independent report. I just want what is being displayed in the JSP page table to be saved as excel.

```
 <div id="searchResultsContents">
        <p>Search Results:</p>
                <display:table class="cspTable"name="searchEmployees" sort="list"
                    pagesize="10" requestURI="employeeSearch.html" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
                    defaultsort="1" defaultorder="ascending">
                    <display:column property="fullName" title="Name" class="namesColumn"
                        sortable="true" href="showUser.html" paramId="employeeId"
                        paramProperty="employeeID" />
                    <display:column property="occupationalTitle.titleName" title="Title"
                        sortable="true" />
                    <display:column property="email" title="Email"
                        sortable="true" />
                    <display:column property="cycle.cycleName" title="Cycle" 
                        sortable="true" />
                    <display:column property="realLocation.code" title="Location"
                        sortable="true" />
                    <display:column property="hireDate" title="Hire Date"
                        sortable="true" />
                </display:table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thank you

Comment: FYI - downloads always come from the server.  You'll need to create a Servlet that streams the data back to the browser.  Normally I just do a CSV but if you want XLSX you'll probably need to mimic the XML format that it uses...  [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Excel "knows" how to open HTML/CSV files, so you can do the following:

1. on the JSP's header add these lines:

   `response.setHeader("Content-disposition:", "attachment; filename='excelfilename.xls';");

   response.setHeader("Authorization", request.getHeader("Authorization"));

   response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");

   response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`
2. make sure the output table is either in CSV or in HTML "table" format

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the DisplayTag library? They incorporate an Export Filter ( http://www.displaytag.org/10/export_filter.html ) that can be used with minimal configuration.